# pip install <package> error - The program can't start because VERSION.dll is missing"

Tags: python, pip

I got an error when trying to run pip install on Window Server

```
pip install <package>
```

> The program can't start because VERSION.dll is missing from your computer

But there's a version.dll in /system32 though, so I have no idea why there's an error.

I think it's either a faulty installation of Visual C++ or .NET framework or Windows but I have limited access to server so I wanted to confirm the cause first

python manage.py also give the same issues

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem is faulty installation of window